# why schema fields is not saving in database using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I'm trying to save the multiple fields file in to mongodb , destination paths are saving but fields are not saving  in mongodb, at what part i'm doing wrong please help me thanks in advance

Schema:-

```
{   
 thumbnail: { type: String, data:Buffer},
 trailerVideo : { type: String, data:Buffer}, 
}
```

Creating an instance to save in mongodb:-

```
const courseFields = new Courses({  
    thumbnail: req.files.path,
    trailerVideo: req.files.path
});
courseFields
  .save(courseFields)
```

multer data:-

```
     const multer = require("multer"),
     storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, 'uploads')
        },

       filename: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, file.originalname);
       }
    });


 const uploadImg = multer({
     storage: storage
  }).fields([{name:'thumbnail'},{name:'trailer'}]);
```

postman:-[image]

Answer (score 0):

`req.files` is an `array`, so you should specify an index of files to get the file path.
If you have only one file in each field. your instance should be:

```js
const courseFields = new Courses({  
    thumbnail: req.files[0].path,
    trailerVideo: req.files[0].path
});
courseFields
  .save(courseFields)
```

or each field has multiple files. You can loop through it to get get a list of paths and store them in an array.

reference:
[multer docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#:%7E:text=%C2%A0%C2%A0//%C2%A0%C2%A0req.files%5B%27avatar,files%5B%27gallery%27%5D%C2%A0-%3E%C2%A0Array)